# How can I load session information into qtwebkit?

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I am building a specialized browser based on Qtwebkit. I would like to save the session information when logging into authenticated websites and load this information again when I restart the browser. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most websites use cookies to store session id. You can save cookies using
[`QList<QNetworkCookie> QNetworkCookieJar::allCookies () const`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkcookiejar.html#allCookies)
and load them back using
[`void QNetworkCookieJar::setAllCookies(const QList<QNetworkCookie> & cookieList)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkcookiejar.html#setAllCookies)
You can get `QNetworkCookieJar` using
[`QNetworkCookieJar * QNetworkAccessManager::cookieJar () const`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#cookieJar)
and you can get `QNetworkAccessManager` being used by `QWebPage` using
[`QNetworkAccessManager * QWebPage::networkAccessManager () const`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebpage.html#networkAccessManager)

Session id can be also stored as part of url or in the hidden form field on the page. If the site uses the former it's enough to save the url and if it uses the latter you have to save the page itself, too.

The task gets more complicated now, when the [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) could be used. If a site makes use of the web storage you should take care of saving and restoring it in addition to all of the above data. You can set the location for offline storage using
[`void QWebSettings::setOfflineStoragePath(const QString & path)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebsettings.html#setOfflineStoragePath)
and get it using
[`QString QWebSettings::offlineStoragePath ()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebsettings.html#offlineStoragePath)
You might get some more information on [webkit-qt](http://lists.webkit.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/webkit-qt) mailing list and on #qtwebkit IRC channel on freenode.net

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to QNetworkCookieJar
virtual member function   `bool CookieHandler::setCookiesFromUrl (const QList<QNetworkCookie> & cookieList, const QUrl & url)` can be used to save cookies into your own persistent storage.
For example,

```
bool CookieHandler::setCookiesFromUrl (const QList<QNetworkCookie> & cookieList, const QUrl & url) {
    foreach(QNetworkCookie i, cookieList) {
    // probably don't want to store session cookies
    if (!i.isSessionCookie()) {
      // save the cookie to own storage format
    }
}
return true;
```

}

protected member function`void QNetworkCookieJar::setAllCookies ( const QList<QNetworkCookie> & cookieList )` is used to restore cookies from your own storage to QNetworkCookieJar since QNetworkCookieJar does not implement permanent storage: it only keeps the cookies in memory.
example code,

```
void CookieHandler::setAllCookiestoJar() {
    // retrieve cookies from local database
    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookieList = this->getCookiesFromLocalDB();
    this->setAllCookies(cookieList);
    // check if they are correctly loaded
    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookieList_tmp = this->allCookies();
    foreach(QNetworkCookie i, cookieList_tmp)
      qDebug() << i.toRawForm(QNetworkCookie::Full);
```

}